# How do I implement a scrolling list view in iPhone programming

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll, uiscrollview

I have a view for an inbox. In the view I can currently show 10 sms messages. After 10 sms messages, I need to be able to scroll the messages.

In other words, how do I implement a scrolview in iPhone programming like the one in the mail inbox or the SMS application?

Comment: Why the downvotes everyone? This is a reasonable question.

Comment: That said, Raju - you've asked a lot of question and not marked a single question answered yet. Why not give someone some rep?

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, you don't want a UIScrollView for a list of SMSs. UIScrollview - which is often referred to simply as a 'Scroll View' is a more general scrolling view.

To implement a list of scrolling cells like 10 SMS Messages, you should use a UITableView. You get get a log of help on UITableView programming here on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableview) or in Apples docs or on Google.

Answer (score -1):

Use UIScrollView class http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html